# OutOfMemory during KubernatesJobExecution

Tags: docker, kubernetes, memory, jvm

I have below resource limits in kubernates pod. where as my image starts with jvm args .
we have added resource limit less than min/max heap . java process started to run for some time and pod got killed abruptly with OutOfmemory.

How can pod start if memory specified in resource limit is 3 times less value ? Could some one help on this ?

```
cmd: 
java -Xmx1512m -Xms1512m $LOGARGS -jar test-ms.jar
```

pod resourcelimits:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 300m
    memory: 500Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 150m
    memory: 300Mi

/start.sh: line 19:     7 Killed                  java -Xmx1512m -Xms1512m $LOGARGS -jar test-ms.jar
```

Comment: You seem to know that the JVM heap limit is set to 3x the resource limits, and hopefully it's obvious how to change one or the other.  You can also probably remove the `java -Xmx -Xms` options to let the JVM determine the memory limits from the container environment ("cgroup memory limits").  Is there more to the question than this?

Comment: which one gets preference jvm args or resources ? if resources how that would be adjusted ?

Comment: Kubernetes will kill the pod if its actual memory usage exceeds `limits:`; it doesn't know what's actually running in the container.

Comment: so this 500mi in limits is for logs, container images, container resources and jvm ? so can there be possiblity that while java process is in progress others might eat up java required memory in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

At 500Mi your but is evicted. If Java requires 1500, this cant work. Raise the memory value in the limit section, play with the value. Your container does not only need memory for Java.

Update to your comment:

Means that when the container reach 500Mi (500 MiB = 524.288 MB) the pod is restarted. To avoid that the pod use to much memory (ex. 10GB) because something inaspect happens. Memoryleaks for example. You limit the memory so that also other pods can run on the node. You must get what is a normal scenario for memory inside your container. As  you are setting memory requirements for java, you can check if you really need them. If your cluster has metrics installed like prometheus.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

You can install:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/high-availability-1.21+.yaml
```

Then to analyse Cpu and memory:

```
kubectl top node // shows values for the nodes

kubectl top pod // shows values for the pods
```

Refere to the documentation if you want to use it.
While your container is running, you can also get inside and execute the normal top linux command.

Comment: so this 500mi in resources is for logs, container images, container resources and jvm ? so can there be possiblity that as java process progress others might eat up java required memory ?

Comment: No, the 500Mi is for memory of the process of the container.